# Trying to get the Lag in partition to show previous value

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the previous value within a certain partition.

I tried to do a Lag Partition over clause and it still gives me NULL.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: should I redo my question?

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54293002/edit) you question and add the information other would need.

Comment: `LAG` will return `NULL` if there's no previous value in the partition. I suspect that's what happens here. What does the data and query look like?

Answer (score 0):

LAG is great windowing function introuducted in MS SQl Server 2012.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE (BusinessEntityID int, SalesYear int,   SalesQuota decimal);
    INSERT INTO @Table  (BusinessEntityID, SalesYear, SalesQuota)
    VALUES
     (275,2005,367000)
    ,(275,2005,556000)
    ,(275,2006,502000)
    ,(275,2006,550000)
    ,(275,2006,1429000)
    ,(275,2006,1324000);

    SELECT BusinessEntityID, SalesYear AS SalesYear, SalesQuota AS CurrentQuota,   
           LAG(SalesQuota, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY SalesYear) AS PreviousQuota  
    FROM @Table
    WHERE BusinessEntityID = 275 and SalesYear IN ('2005','2006');
```

The result of executing query:

```
   BusinessEntityID SalesYear   CurrentQuota    PreviousQuota
   275                  2005    367000                0
   275                  2005    556000                367000
   275                  2006    502000                556000
   275                  2006    550000                502000
   275                  2006    1429000               550000
   275                  2006    1324000               1429000
```

Comment: The OP is already using `LAG` and asks why the results contain NULLs.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I hope hi will notice in my answer how to structure question, provide data and example of code.